# FormGroup FormArray - remove only one element object by name. Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, formarray

```
    {
  "companies": [
    {
      "company": "example comany",
      "projects": [
        {
          "projectName": "example project",
          "numero": ""
        },
        {
          "projectName": "example project",
          "numero": ""
        },
        {
          "projectName": "example project",
          "numero": ""
        },
        {
          "projectName": "example project",
          "numero": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove projectName  from formGroup before when I send my form POST request. Is it possible? I tried use reset method, but this remove all elements
https://stackblitz.com/edit/generar-json?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Could you format this a bit nicer?

Comment: I could not find code that does a post request. Could you please add your current version and describe what's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

basically what you need is a map, to get a new `Array` without your selected option

```js
let object = {
  "companies": [{
    "company": "example comany",
    "projects": [{
        "projectName": "example project",
        "numero": ""
      },
      {
        "projectName": "example project",
        "numero": ""
      },
      {
        "projectName": "example project",
        "numero": ""
      },
      {
        "projectName": "example project",
        "numero": "3"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

object.companies = object.companies.map(company => {
  company.projects = company.projects.map(project => {
    delete project['projectName']; // we delete the key on project each.
    return project;
  });
  return company
});
console.log(object)
```

Comment: thank you I thank you from my heart I still need to learn a lot, try to do the hardest thing, i try to create an equal copy of formgroup

Comment: you can do a deepcopy before doing this, take into account that `delete project['projectName']` is destructive, you wont be able to use it again. unless you already have a copy of that information :D